# Pathfinding across map Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know exactly how to explain this, but, I'm attempting to make a game where a user controls a nation.

The game basically consists of a map, which consists of nations, which all control different provinces, which are defined in a bmp file where each is represented by a different color,

[image: here is a screenshot of part of the file]

I could not send the whole thing as it was too big.

One of the primary game functions is soldiers, which can be moved across these provinces and used to occupy enemy territory or preform other similar tasks. For these soldiers to be able to move across this map, I need them to be able to find a path to the target province. I have not experimented much with path finding before, but from what I understand a path finding algorithm like A* or Dijkstra’s Algorithm would be what I need to use, and that these algorithms require nodes, representing the locations, and connections to function.

The nodes would then, in this case, have to be somewhere in the province near the center, and as I found this to be rather too complicated to produce using C#, I made another map

[image: here is a screenshot of part of that one]

where the nodes are represented by black pixels, and I plan on creating a script that checks which pixels are black and set these to nodes.

From here, the only thing left for me would be connections.

I now require a way to determine connections, and I honestly have how I would do this. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could present to me a solution, and thank you in advance!

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Better way is to keep the question simple as possible. Rather than whole paragraph, divide it to number of points.

Comment: You need to create some type of dataset that includes each possible node. You can do this programmatically, or you can do it manually, and the dataset can be anything, a list, a dictionary, an array, anything you can loop over or access individual items. Each item in the dataset would include its own value, and a reference to which values it "touches" on the map. Then, your pathfinding algorithm will iterate over the list, probably multiple times, to find the shortest number of nodes from its starting node to the ending node. If this sounds complicated and expensive, it is, pathfinding is hard

Comment: I think this question is more suited for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

what you can try to do is Unity's in build Nav Mesh system. It is very easy to use.

Essentially, you create a pathing system - roads, rivers etc. Then you can bake the area for path finding. Essentially how it works is you will have a agent and you can set a location he has to go to. It will then find a path with the baked area.

Simply what you do then is use right-click to set the location. This can be done with a raycast. Goodluck, hope this helps.